# AngularJS multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Sorry if this seems like a noob question, but it's because I am a noob.  I have been researching and cannot find an answer.  I tried figuring it out myself but I just end up screwing up more stuff.

I have a controller grabbing data from a JSON URL.  The issue is I want another controller (using same API/JSON) but it has a slightly different URL, same server.

Below is the code that is working, so I just need to tweak/duplicate it to grab JSON data from the URL adding /podcast/

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, $http, DataLoader, $timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.url = 'http://genesis2media.com/mobile/wp-json/wp/v2/';

    console.log('PostsCtrl');

    $scope.loadPosts = function() {

        DataLoader.get($rootScope.url + 'posts').then(function(response) {
            $scope.posts = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('error', response);
        });

    }

    // Load posts on page load
    $scope.loadPosts();

    paged = 2;
    $scope.moreItems = true;

    // Load more (infinite scroll)
    $scope.loadMore = function() {

        if (!$scope.moreItems) {
            return;
        }

        var pg = paged++;

        $timeout(function() {

            DataLoader.get($rootScope.url + 'posts' + '?page=' + pg).then(function(response) {

                angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.posts.push(value);
                });

                if (response.data.length <= 0) {
                    $scope.moreItems = false;
                }
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.moreItems = false;
                console.log('error');
            });

            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

        }, 1000);

    }

    $scope.moreDataExists = function() {
        return $scope.moreItems;
    }

    // Pull to refresh
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {

        console.log('Refreshing!');
        $timeout(function() {

            $scope.loadPosts();

            //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

        }, 1000);

    };

})

.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $sce) {

    $ionicLoading.show({
        noBackdrop: true
    });

    var singlePostApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts/' + $stateParams.postId;

    DataLoader.get(singlePostApi).then(function(response) {
        $scope.post = response.data;
        // Don't strip post html
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.content.rendered);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('error', response);
    });

});
```

Comment: If you want to reuse some logic between controllers you should put it into a service https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I think that's above me at the moment.

Comment: yes, use a shared service to I think you can also use `angular.extend` to the controller. but using `shared services` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for,

Shared Service Example

```
var app = angular.module('project',[]);
app.factory('sharedService', function($http) {  
    return {
        method:functon() {
            // do your stuff $http.get/post
            // return data
        }
    };
});
function FirstCtrl($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.data= sharedService.method();
}
function SecondCtrl($scope, sharedService) {    
    $scope.data= sharedService.method(); 
}
```